# Can't click on links, mark text, how can I fix this?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website, and I've added a list and made the list links to different websites.

The problem is that on the website it shows that they are links but I can't click them, or mark them or anything. I can't mark the text on the website either.

Comment: Please show the code you have written.

Comment: No HTML, no CSS, not even a link. How are we supposed to answer this?

Comment: All due respect, your explanation is vague to an outsider. Please provide a bit of code or something to make an answer possible. When you say list do you mean HTML markup? ie <ol>/<ul>

Answer (score 2):

Yes a bit of your code would be helpful.

But it sounds, that some container overlapping your content if you reduce the size of your Browser-Window.

Just check that

Edit // If that is the problem, try to give your content a higher z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not using the `<a>` element.

See [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) on how to make a link.